# How to combine not matching 3-dimensional arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I have read some features from two different sources and now I have two `ndarray`s of shapes `(152, 45, 70)`, `(152, 45, 200)` how can I combine them to get one array of shape `(152, 45, 270)`?

Comment: But they are matching...

Comment: In your example, you aren't combining them. You are only adding the last dimension values. Is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: mm.. sorry.. It works now with np.concatenate((X1, X2), axis=2) .. I had a problem with my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [`concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) along the axis you care about:

```
a = np.empty((152, 45, 70))
b = no.empty((152, 45, 200)) 

c = np.concatenate((a, b), axis=2)
```

OR

```
c = np.concatenate((a, b), axis=-1)
```